# PPP connection through serial cable works on WindowsXP but doesn't work on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, serial-port, ppp

I have a device that establishes PPP connection (or incoming connection in terms of Windows) through null-modem cable and then communicates with PC using TCP sockets API.

The problem is that all works fine on WindowsXP but does not work on Windows7. As far as I understand there are some troubles with establishing PPP connection because it doesn't get to TCP socket connection.

Here is handshake procedure log (from communication cable properties in device manager) on WindowsXP:

> 10-27-2011 14:37:04.342 - Recv: CLIENT
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.342 - Interpreted response: Ring
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.357 - TSP(0000): LINEEVENT: LINE_NEWCALL
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.357 - TSP(0000): LINEEVENT: LINECALLSTATE_OFFERING
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.357 - TSP(0000): LINEEVENT: LINEDEVSTATE_RINGING(0x1)
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - Recv: CLIENT
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - Interpreted response: Ring
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - TSP(0000): LINEEVENT: LINEDEVSTATE_RINGING(0x1)
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - TSP(0000): Accepting Call
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - TSP(0000): LINEEVENT: LINECALLSTATE_ACCEPTED
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - TSP(0000): Answering Call
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - Answering the call.
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - Send: CLIENTSERVER
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - Connection established at 115200bps.
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - Error-control off or unknown.
>   10-27-2011 14:37:04.545 - Data compression off or unknown.

and on Windows7:

> 10-27-2011 13:27:30.447 - Recv: CLIENT
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.447 - Interpreted response: Ring
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.647 - Recv: CLIENT
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.647 - Interpreted response: Ring
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.847 - Recv: CLIENT
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.847 - Interpreted response: Ring
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.847 - Answering the call.
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.857 - Send: CLIENTSERVER
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.857 - Connection established at 115200bps.
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.857 - Error-control off or unknown.
>   10-27-2011 13:27:30.857 - Data compression off or unknown.
>   10-27-2011 13:27:32.415 - Hanging up the modem.
>   10-27-2011 13:27:32.416 - Hardware hangup by lowering DTR.
>   10-27-2011 13:27:32.416 - 115200,8,N,1, ctsfl=1, rtsctl=2
>   10-27-2011 13:27:32.416 - Initializing modem.
>   10-27-2011 13:27:32.416 - Waiting for a call.

I was assuming that some needed Windows services were stopped but couldn't find which services exactly need to be started and at the first look the same services were started in both cases.

So, does anyone know what the problem is and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there anything in the system or application event log that would help troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: @ShaneWealti , Application just opens TCP socket and waits for device to connect. According to application event there is no incoming activity on this socket. Connection through serial cable is establishing with the help of Windows wizzard (New Incoming Connection). The only log I found is in the question. It's from Device Manager -> Device Properties -> Diagnostic -> Event Log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by manually editing the *rasphone.pbk* file on the computer and changing the *Type* value to 3 (3=RASET_Direct (Direct serial or parallel connection.)) instead of 1 (1=RASET_Phone (Phone line, for example, modem, ISDN, X.25)). Apparently this is a bug in windows 7 that *depends on the device*.

The *rasphone.pbk* file can be found by opening up an explorer window and typing the following into the address bar:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\
```

The *rasphone.pbk* file should be in that folder.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/5858797c-bc75-4e3f-bca4-d988fadd7581

Comment: This is related to an issue with Windows 7/8 Dial-up Connections (DUN) using the modem type _Communications cable between two computers_.  Also known as _PPP-over-null-modem_, _PPP-over-direct-serial_, _PPP-over-direct-cable-connect_

Comment: More search terms: Windows 7 Dialup Error 777, Win7 DUN Error 777, Windows 7 PPP over Dial Up Error 777, Windows 7 PPP RAS Dial Up Error 777, Win7 RAS Error 777, Win7 Dial-up Error 777, rasphone.pbk, RASENTRY Structure, dwType RASET_Direct. Also, look at "manually editing rasphone.pbk" in [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/5858797c-bc75-4e3f-bca4-d988fadd7581/setting-up-a-ppp-connection-using-communications-cable-between-two-computers?forum=w7itpronetworking)

Comment: [RASENTRY Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377274(v=vs.85).aspx), dwType - The type of phone-book entry: RASET_Direct - Direct serial or parallel connection.